# Date difference when using input type date together with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, date

I am using the date input type so users can select dates:

```
<input type="date" name="start" ng-model="formData.start">
```

Before the data is sent to the server, I see it as this:

```
console.log("start: " + $scope.formData.start);
start: Sat Jan 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT +0100 (CET)
```

In my MySQL database it is saved as this:

```
2016-01-08 23:00:00
```

So it seems like there is a difference of 1 hour. The problem is that this hour changes the date from one day to the day before. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date is correct:

You input `Sat Jan 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT +0100 (CET)` note the `GMT +0100`. That indicates that the timezone of this date is one hour off (later).

So without the timezone `2016-01-08 23:00:00` is perfectly correct! (GMT +0)

TLDR: both dates are the same

Example:

```js
var date = new Date("Sat Jan 09 2016 00:00:00 GMT +0100 (CET)")
document.write(date.toUTCString())
```